# Transfer $50k to another person's account (in California, USA)

Tags: united-states, taxes, money-transfer

I am buying a house for me and my girlfriend. As I used most of my saving for the closing fees (she is not on the loan) she wants to transfer $50k to me to pay for furniture and landscaping fees.

Is the amount going to be a problem? We dont want to be taxed or cause any trouble with the law.

Answer (score 1):

A non-cash transaction will not be a problem. The bank will have to fill out federal paperwork if there are large amounts of cash involved.  This is to stop the underground economy.

This can even extend to non-banks. If you were to walk into a car dealer or some other stores and hand them a bag  of cash they will also report it.

You can do what you propose without having to transfer any money between accounts. Your girlfriend can put the furniture and landscaping on her credit card, or write checks to the stores or companies.

Based on the number of questions on this site regarding how to transfer funds between banks and accounts, the mechanics of the transfer is the hard part. Resist the urge to use cash to make the transfer. That will require paperwork. Many people find that the old standard of using checks to transfer funds is easy, safe and quick.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be a problem; people regularly move larger sums. It *will* be reported to law authorities as large enough to be potentially of interest, but since you can explain it that's fine.

Comment: "*Will* be reported" might be too strong.  You might be thinking of a [Currency Transaction Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_transaction_report) which applies to transactions of over $10,000, but only if they are in physical currency, which would not normally be the case for a bank transfer.  The only other such report I know of is a [Suspicious Activity Report](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspicious_activity_report), but that would only apply if the bank actually thought the transaction was suspicious; they might, but they might not.